# angularjs constant for material icon

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I currently have a constant reusable with text as below. However, I would like to replace with material icons.

How to make it work?

Current code

```
.constant('$abbreviationProvider', {
    "Legend": {
        "B": "Bull",
        "S": "Sheep",
        "H": "Horse"
    },
```

I make it to

```
.constant('$abbreviationProvider', {
    "Legend": {
        "B": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE861;</i>',
        "S": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE862;</i>',
        "H": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE863;</i>',
    },
```

Unfortunately, only text is display. I want the icons to display

How to do it?

Comment: Where is your code that displays the items?

Comment: Check the below answer and see if it is what you are looking for? @lotteryman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filter to achieve this with the help of  `$sce` of `ngSanitize` directive

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',["ngSanitize"]);
    
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$sce', '$scope', function($sce, $scope) {
        $scope.detail = {
            "Legend": {
                "B": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE861;</i>',
                "S": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE862;</i>',
                "H": '<i class="material-icons">&#xE863;</i>'
            }
        };
    }]);
    myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in detail.Legend"><span ng-bind-html="val | unsafe"></span></div>
</body>
```

**For more Info**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce